# Is it better to do or skip audits?

Tags: support, review-audits

There are a lot of audits that are really obvious to spot. In queues where you have the possibility to do so, I tend to hit "skip" on them, because if I chose the right action, I am presented with a "Congratulations" dialogue, and then have to click on "Next", which means one click (and a few seconds load wait time sometimes) more.

Now I have been wondering if this is a good idea. The review ban algorithm might take into account the number of failed audits vs. the number of passed audits, which means that skipping a lot of audits may bias the numbers more towards failed for the occasional failed audit.

So, does skipping instead of passing an audit make any difference (in view of later reactions to failed review audits)? Is there any other drawback at this?

Comment: I would be surprised if there was a drawback. They are meant to catch out robo-reviewers. The only "problem" I could think of is if you were to perform consistent crappy reviews, yet skip all the audits. That might get you some extra attention if noticed. But surely that's not the case here. ;)

Comment: The system is so broken right now, that I wouldn't blame anybody for skipping through the reviews. I hope at some point that try to get some humans involved in the process so that the audits can be meaningful and applicable. I just hope that people don't lose their enthusiasm and give up on the system altogether.

Comment: *`The review ban algorithm might take into account the number of failed audits vs. the number of passed audits,`* I am not so sure this is the case. I think the passed audits are not taken into account as much as you may think - I think it's mostly based on the failed audits in time between them.

Comment: If it's so obvious and you've spent perhaps up to a minute working that out, then just take the right action. What's the harm in an extra click and waiting a few seconds for the new review to load? Surely it's better to simply have more review audits passed under your belt, so that if at some point you fail an audit the ratio is lower?

Comment: @Tanner: "Obvious" and "spent up to a minute" don't work well together for me.  I am talking about those blatantly obvious ones that jump into your eyes in a fraction of a second, like the vandalism suggested edit audits. It might not even only be the extra 20 seconds wasted on doing nothing useful, it might also be the disappointment that certain audits are so blatantly obvious that they catch nothing but badly written scripts.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I initially wrote "5-10 seconds", but rewrote. I guess time is money...

Answer (score 15):

If you successfully complete an audit, you get credit for a successful review towards badges and it shows up in your review history. If you skip it, it'll just be like you skipped any other review. But I don't think there is any explicit penalty for skipping the audits, or would it really draw attention to yourself.

From the [FAQ about review audits on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/215013), it sounds like the number of review audits you've successfully completed does not factor into a automated review queue ban<sup>1</sup>. Only the number you've failed and the period of time. To be noted as well, moderators do possess the ability to suspend someone's ability to view due their actions in the review queues, regardless of the the track record with audits.

<sup><sup>1</sup> I'm not an developer, so I don't know the exact formula</sup>

Comment: I actually do have queries to look for folks who always skip audits and never skip anything else. Also folks who always review one way on audits and never that way on anything else. Not saying everyone who does this gets blocked from review, but... Probably worthwhile to not make it look too much like you're just in it for the chance to click buttons.

Comment: I estimate the risk of getting a broken audit higher than any theoretical penalty from skipping them, so I almost always skip if the item looks like an audit.

Comment: But how are we going to fix the system if we just skip bad audits? Why aren't there humans involved?

Comment: @Shog9 Sounds like if they always skip just audits that they're paying attention.

Comment: @Shog9 but... but... they are shinny buttons, I have to press them :(

Comment: Make the Skip button shinier!